declare a type that returns another generic type
I am not sure how to describe it, so I will write an example :
// This works for an observable
type UnwrappedObs<T> = T extends Observable<infer T> ? T : never;
// This works for a promise
type UnwrappedPro<T> = T extends PromiseLike<infer T> ? T : never;

// This should work for any class that accepts a generic type
type UnwrappedAll<T> = T extends GenericClass<infer T> ? T : never;

How can I declare GenericClass so that it can accept anything that is generic, like Observable | Promise | Pick | Omit | Partial | ... ?

This question doesn't quite make sense to me as written. Even if TS had the ability to abstract over generic types (which would require ms/TS#1213 to work), I don't see what GenericClass could possibly be. TypeScript's type system isn't nominal. If I define type Foo<T> = Array<{x: T}>, then presumably you'd want UnwappedAll<Foo<string>> to be string. But Foo is just a type alias, so then UnwrappedAll<Array<{x: string}>> would also have to be string. But shouldn't it be {x: string}? That's inconsistent, and thus impossible.

(see prev comment.) Could you please [edit] to clarify what you could mean by GenericClass in light of this issue? Also note that Pick and Omit take multiple type arguments, so what would UnwrappedAll<Pick<T, K>> give you? T? K? something else?

@jcalz I will not clarify because indeed it seems impossible, so there's no point in giving more details. I have voted to close this question and so should you if you wish ! as for Partial and Omit, indeed I made a mistake using them in this example, sorry about that !

You just cant unwrap anything because TypeScript types are structural, sorry but it is not possible to achieve what u want to do.
